# How to get and use the version of artifact

Tags: ant, ivy

when there is a dependency, that is defined in the ivy.xml, e.g. like this:

```
<dependency org="com.company" name="mypackage" rev="6.0.0"/>
```

and in the build.xml, i let ivy retrieve it. Then it downloads a file with version id in the name. E.g. lib/mypackage-6.0.0.zip

How can i know the version (6.0.0) or the full name in my ANT build, without repeating the version from ivy.xml manually/dedundantly?

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
<unzip src="lib/mypackage-${version}.zip" ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

One approach is to use the [artifactpropery](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/artifactproperty.html) task, to set a property with the dependency version, based on a pattern similar to how the [retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) task works.

```
<ivy:artifactproperty name="[artifact].ver" value="[revision]"/>

<echo message="Version: ${slf4j-api.ver}"/>
```

### Option 2

My alternate preference is to use configurations and simply create a file in the build workspace that has no revision in it's filename as follows:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="target/zips/[artifact].[ext]" conf="zips"/>
```

This requires an ivy file that has a special "zips" configuration setup and a configuration mapping on the dependency declaration:

```
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.5" conf="zips->default"/>
```

---

## Example (Option 2)

In this example 3 different classpaths are setup under the "lib" directory and a zips directory is populated with a jar file without a revision in its filename:

```
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml
├── lib
│   ├── compile
│   │   └── slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
│   ├── runtime
│   │   ├── log4j-1.2.17.jar
│   │   ├── slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
│   │   └── slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
│   └── test
│       ├── hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
│       ├── junit-4.11.jar
│       ├── log4j-1.2.17.jar
│       ├── slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
│       └── slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
└── target
    └── zips
        └── slf4j-api.jar
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:resolve/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="resolve">
        <!-- Populate the "lib" directory -->
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="compile,runtime,test"/>

        <!-- Populate the "target/zips" directory -->
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="target/zips/[artifact].[ext]" conf="zips"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="runtime" description="Additional run-time dependencies" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="runtime"/>
        <conf name="zips"    description="Additional configuration for demo"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- zips + compile dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.5" conf="zips,compile->default"/>

        <!-- runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.5" conf="runtime->default"/>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.11" conf="test->default"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Note:

- slf4j-api is included in both the "zips" and "compile" configurations.

Comment: I tried Option 1 and it works well for. Thanks for your help!